# Is “A programmer-defined type.” a right definition of "class" in Python?

Tags: object-oriented, python, terminology, class, python-3.x

In *Think Python 2e* **"class"** is defined as *["A programmer-defined type. A class definition creates a new class object."](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython2/html/thinkpython2016.html#sec185)*

But isn't a built-in type considered a **class** too?

Using *Python 3.4.0*, the following code:

```
class File:
    """Represents a computer file."""
    ...

print(type(str))
print(type(File))
print(type("Mahmud"))
print(type(File()))
```

has the following output:

```
<class 'type'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'str'>
<class '__main__.File'>
```

. So here we can notice that the instances of *both* the built-in type `str` and the programmer-defined type `File` belong to `<class 'str'>` and `<class '__main__.File'>`, respectively, so both `str` and `File` are considered **classes**, as I understand. So, is the definition right? If so, how is it right and what do I misunderstand or don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But isn't a built-in type considered a class too?

Yes, it is. The author of the article you linked to is *somewhat* correct, but his definition is lacking. A more complete definition of a class in Python is: *any type that is defined whether user-created or built-in*. A class is essentially a blueprint for creating an object, regardless of whether the "blueprint" is defined at the C level - such as with builtins - or at the Python level such as with user defined types.

However, normally when you think of a class in Python, you are thinking specifically about user-defined classes. But as I made clear above, that's not necessarily the correct way to think of classes. So while the definition may not be completely *wrong*, it is not correct either.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "technically correct"? How can he be so, when his definition is lacking?

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib What I meant to convey is what amon said as well. The author's definition of a class is correct, but would probably mislead one to think that is exclusive what classes are.

Comment: @MahmudMuhammadNaguib But I in hindsight, I think "technically" is the wrong word, as the docs do mention `list`, `int` and the other builtin types as classes. "somewhat" would probably fit better.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2, you'll notice that built-in types are sometimes distinct from user-defined types (classes):

```py
>>> type(str)
<type 'type'>
>>> type("Mahmud")
<type 'str'>
>>> str
<type 'str'>

>>> class OldStyleClass:
...    pass
...
>>> type(OldStyleClass)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> type(OldStyleClass())
<type 'instance'>
>>> OldStyleClass
<class ...OldStyleClass at 0x...>

>>> class NewStyleClass(object):
...    pass
...
>>> type(NewStyleClass)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(NewStyleClass())
<class 'NewStyleClass'>
>>> NewStyleClass
<class 'NewStyleClass'>
```

So we have three distinct cases:

- builtin types like `str`
- old style classes
- new style classes which inherit from `object`.

```
           type(X)            X                   type(X())
           -----------------  ------------------  -----------------
builtin    <type 'type'>      <type 'X'>          <type 'X'>
old style  <type 'classobj'>  <class X at 0x...>  <type 'instance'>
new style  <type 'type'>      <class 'X'>         <class 'X'>
```

The differences between these cases are subtle and have become less important over time. In earlier Python versions, the internal representation affected the reflection capabilities. A remnant of these issues in Python 2.7 is that `type(X()) == X` is false when X is an old-style class!

So for Python 2.x there are some differences between builtin-types and user-defined classes, even though all of them can be used as classes (instantiated, inherited from, …). I consider the author's statement correct, though slightly misleading. It would be more correct to say:

> The `class` keyword allows programmers to define additional classes.

or

> Each value has a *class* or *type* which contains available methods. You can add your own classes with the `class` keyword.

(Of course, a `class` definition is not the only way to define a new class. The `type(…)` constructor comes to mind, as would C extensions.)

In Python 3, these three cases have been combined and there is no visible difference between built-in and user-defined classes.